# Azure Java SDK - Where have classes gone

Tags: java, azure, azure-management-api, azure-java-sdk

I am using the Java sdk to try and automate some azure tasks like start a server and shutdown a server.
I was using version 0.9.0 of the java sdk from the maven

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
            </dependency>   

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-svc-mgmt-compute</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

This code compiled and ran successfully in eclipse

```
 package com.services.servers.operations.azure;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.KeyStoreType;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.ComputeManagementService;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperations;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.configuration.ManagementConfiguration;

public class AzureTest {

    String uri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
    String subscriptionId = "dasdas9-86da-4343-a1f4-24c20864e166";
    String keyStoreLocation = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\azure\\testKeystore.jks";
    String keyStorePassword = "password";

    public boolean startVirtualMachine(String serviceName, String deploymentName, String virtualMachineName){

        boolean isSuccess = true;

        try {            

            VirtualMachineOperations virtualMachineOperations = null;

            Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(
                        new URI(uri), 
                          subscriptionId,
                          keyStoreLocation, 
                          keyStorePassword, 
                          KeyStoreType.jks 
                      );

            ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = ComputeManagementService.create(config);

            virtualMachineOperations = computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations();

            virtualMachineOperations.beginStarting(serviceName, deploymentName, virtualMachineName);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IOException has occured. Exception: " +e);
            isSuccess = false;
        }  catch (ServiceException e) {
            System.out.println("A ServiceException has occured. Exception: " + e);
            isSuccess = false;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("A URISyntaxException has occured. Exception: " + e);
            isSuccess = false;
        }         


        return isSuccess;
    }

}
```

When I upgrade to the latest version of the sdk - 0.9.1 - the following classes dont exist any longer

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.utils.KeyStoreType;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.configuration.ManagementConfiguration;
```

I couldnt find anything online to state where these classes have gone to - whether they have been deprecated or more to another lib

If anyone has any idea what classes I should instead or what libs they may have moved to- that would be great
Or if anyone can suggest any improvements to the above code for starting a server that would be much appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, I got the error `Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.microsoft.azure:azure-svc-mgmt...jar:0.9.0`.

It seems that the issue is caused by the maven repository for downloading the dependencies of the version `0.9.1` of Microsoft Azure SDK for Management.

I suggest you can use the version `0.9.0` for the present.

If you have to use the version `0.9.1`, you can add the complete maven list for the libraries and their dependencies manually in the `pom.xml` file, or you can download & add all library files into the project classpath manually.

Comment: Hi Peter. thanks for getting back to me. Yes I stuck with version 0.9.0 for now. I waas looking at the api docs (http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/) and it did not say anywhere if classes were deprecated so I was wondering the same about the maven repo. Also - do you know is there a page to show the latest api docs? e.g. a http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/latest type url?

Comment: @Damo The page `azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java` as a static web page generated by jekyll and hosted on Github that only show the latest api docs if the related project release a new version and generate the new javadocs. There is not a path `latest` for the page.

Comment: ok fair enough.I have concerns here when looking at duplicate classes like this http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.html and http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.html. Should we be using classes in the package structure com.microsoft.azure. or com.microsoft.windowsazure.? com.microsoft.azure. seems more current to me

Comment: @Damo The classes in the package `azure` are different from the classes in the package `windowsazure`. They respectively corresponding to different services `Resource Management` & `Service Management` that need different authenticating request. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx to know the difference for authenticating.

Answer (score 1):

go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=690320&clcid=0x409, download the file 'PackageForAzureLibrariesForJava.zip' and put these jar files to your project build path or add dependency in pom file if you are using maven. I have tested this in my local. It works.